# How do I layer multiple layers of images in a Max / MSP patch?

Tags: max-msp-jitter

have a photo attached to explain the concept, but essentially, I want to have a background video or image with multiple pngs layered on top like so.

[image]

how would I achieve this? I sense that jit.alphablend is a component of this...

I have also posed this to the MAX forums here http://cycling74.com/forums/topic.php?id=39707 the sample patch I have created is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer was found here, http://cycling74.com/forums/topic.php?id=39389

1. each "layer" gets connected to a jit.gl.videoplane object
2. all "layers" get routed to a jit.gl.render object
3. the jit.gl.render object gets routed to a jit.window ob (or similar)